# How to monitor Spark job with Airflow

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I set up a few dags, which eventually ends with a spark-submit command to a spark cluster. I'm using cluster mode if that makes a difference. Anyways, so my code works, but I realized if the spark job were to fail, I wouldn't necessarily know from within the Airflow UI. By triggering the job via cluster mode, Airflow hands off the job to an available worker, therefore airflow has no knowledge of the spark job.

How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Airflow (from version 1.8) has

```
SparkSqlOperator - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_sql_operator.py ;
SparkSQLHook code - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_sql_hook.py
SparkSubmitOperator - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py
SparkSubmitHook code - https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/spark_submit_hook.py
```

If you use these, the airflow task will fail if the spark job fails. You might have to change the logging part in the spark_submit_hook file if you use spark1.x to get real time logs, because spark-submit logs even the errors to stdout for some of 1.x versions (I had to make changes for 1.6.1).

Also note that there have been many improvements to the SparkSubmitOperator since last stable release.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using `client` mode, since the client will not terminate until the spark job is complete. Airflow executor can pick up the exit code.

Otherwise you may need to use a job server. Check out https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: We considered this but wouldn't we need our airflow box to be part of the Spark cluster if we were to use `client` mode? I'm still new to Spark, when we tried `client` mode, no jobs kicked off until I started the Spark worker on said box.

Comment: You will need to run `spark-submit` on the same host as Airflow worker. That worker node must be able communicate with the Spark cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can start leveraging the LivyOperator which will take care of monitoring the job,
LivyOperator will poll the status of your Spark job at interval you will configure to poll.
Example:

```
kickoff_streamer_task = LivyOperator(
    task_id='kickoff_streamer_task',
    dag=dag,
    livy_conn_id='lokori',
    file='abfs://data@amethiaprime.dfs.core.windows.net/user/draxuser/drax_streamer.jar',
    **polling_interval=60**,  # used when you want to pull the status of submitted job
    queue='root.ids.draxuser',
    proxy_user='draxuser',
    args=['10', '3000'],
    num_executors=4,
    conf={
        'spark.shuffle.compress': 'false',
        'master': 'yarn',
        'deploy_mode': 'cluster',
        'spark.ui.view.acls': '*'
    },
    class_name='com.apple.core.drax.dpaas.batch.DraxMatrixProducer',
    on_success_callback=livy_callback,
    on_failure_callback=_failure_callback
)
```

In the above example, polling_interval set to 60 seconds, it will keep on polling the status of your job at the 60s, it will make sure to give you the correct status of your job.